# Kernel 5.8 crash on ubuntu 20.04 and ubuntu 20.10

Tags: kernel, lubuntu, do-release-upgrade, downgrade

I have had problems with the system after installing ubuntu 20.04 and 20.10, both freeze and do not let me operate, desktop, mouse ... frozen completely.
I have downgraded both systems to kernel 5.4 and without problems from what I deduce that there are shots.
I dislike having to go around patching things up like that and not being able to use them natively but hey, for now I have no other choice.
I had been using Ubuntu 20.4 without problems for many months until after an update the system froze, at that time I did not know why until I installed Ubuntu 20.10 and it happened again, after several tests with both systems I have reached the point where which I have installed the kernel 5.4, and in this way they work fine but it is a botch.
Has the same happened to someone? Does someone who controls these issues occurs or knows what is happening?
If I can help someone who is in the same situation, let me know and I will gladly try to do it.

Comment: My Lubuntu 20.04 LTS (*focal*) systems are all using the 5.4 kernel at this point in time.  Yes *groovy* or 20.10 are using 5.8 (as is this *hirsute*) but I'm confused by your mention of 5.8 in 20.04/focal as even QA-test installs for 20.04.2 result in a 5.4 kernel installed (tests performed this week; though I'm expecting that to change before 20.04.2's release)

Comment: FYI:   I just zsync'd the lastest Lubuntu daily ISO for *focal* or 20.04.2 [2021-01-14] and kernel is 5.4.0-62 on install, but upgrades to 5.4.0-63 only; not 5.8 as you seem to indicate by my reading of your question.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem seemed to be an "out of memory" condition on my desktop system running a recently installed (L)ubuntu 20.10 (Groovy Gorilla) OS.  I solved the problem by creating a swapfile per the excellent instructions published by Brian Boucheron at https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-space-on-ubuntu-20-04.
Interestingly, judging from what I see on my older computer running Lubuntu 18.04 (bionic), it appears that on this and earlier releases swapfiles were set up and enabled by default, but that at some point in later releases they were not.

I hope this may be of some help.